# insert user profile tank auth

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I've seen question from this [CodeIgniter: Passing fields to user_profiles database with Tank_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908899/codeigniter-passing-fields-to-user-profiles-database-with-tank-auth)

and my problem same as Davezatch have, but mine like this on auth controller:

```
...
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {                                // validation ok
            if (!is_null($data = $this->tank_auth->create_user(
                    $use_username ? $this->form_validation->set_value('username') : '',
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('email'),                     
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('password'),                      
                    $this->form_validation->set_value('webiste'),
                    $email_activation))) {  
...
```

when sending to my email, it show like this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 
Notice Message: Undefined variable:
new_email_key Filename: email/activate-html.php 
Line Number: 14
```

any suggestion?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the new_email_key , that is used to activate the account. Check if it is present in your database also check your config for email activation .

Comment: the new_email_key is still present on my database, and my email activation is set true on my config, so where the missing one you mean?
thank you