# Codeigniter Tank_auth adding fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I use CI tank_auth library to have user's registration form and need to add new fields that tank_auth didn't come with.

I did refer to this [Tank Auth Adding Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070326/tank-auth-adding-fields), but it never helps me to solve my doubt.

Let's say, I want to have additional '**Name**' field during registration, I had created it in views and `function register()` controller, that's works fine except when I want to put it in `user_profiles` table, I created a column called `name`, and then in tank_auth model's users.php, I find below method and added:

```
private function create_profile($user_id, $name)
{
    $this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->set('name', $name);
    return $this->db->insert($this->profile_table_name);
}
```

When I run registration, no error occurred, I check with the table, the `name` field is not insert, so I guess it might be no parameter pass to `$name`, here is my problem, where could I pass the parameter to this function?

I hope there is someone with experiences with this library can clear my doubt.

Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**

**@Joan-Diego Rodriguez** has a very good practice on how to add additional fields into tank_auth's user_profiles table during register process.

[CodeIgniter: Passing fields to user_profiles database with Tank_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908899/codeigniter-passing-fields-to-user-profiles-database-with-tank-auth)

Hope this would help someone who looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I came across this problem already, my solution is simple

create user -> create user_profiles -> update user_profiles

please go to TA model "users" and add this method/function

```
function update_user_profile($user_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->update($this->profile_table_name, $data);
}
```

make copy of auth.php (just in case) and in register method do some adjustments (as follows) please note **here is some more code** put original in there (I modified mine).

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
// validation ok

    if (!is_null(<here is some more code>)) {

        $user_data = array(
    'first_name' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->form_validation->set_value('last_name'),
    );

    //$this->load->model('tank_auth/users');
    $this->users->update_user_profile($data['user_id'], $user_data); //update happens

    } else {

        $errors = $this->tank_auth->get_error_message();
        foreach ($errors as $k => $v)   $data['errors'][$k] = $this->lang->line($v);

    }
}
```

**edit**
to get user you need to use SQLs JOIN as example shows (with extra first_name/last_name) I hope you will get the idea

retrieve all users put this in users model

```
function get_all_users() {
    $this->db->select('users.id, users.username, users.activated, users.banned, users.ban_reason, user_profiles.id as up_id, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'users.id = user_profiles.user_id');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

retrieve one user (just added where clause)

```
function get_ser($id){
    $this->db->select('users.id, users.username, users.activated, users.banned, users.ban_reason, user_profiles.id as up_id, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('user_profiles', 'users.id = user_profiles.user_id');
    $this->db->where('users.id', $id);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result()[0] : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could have any idea of how to retrieve user's info from `user_profiles` table?